# MysqlWorkbench 8.0 @OneToOne 1:1 Mapping not working

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mapping, mysql-workbench, reverse-engineering, forward-engineer

I used reverse engineering in myysqlworkbench to map entities.
However, bugs occur in 1:1 identification mapping.

Bug: After one-to-one mapping, it works well until forward engineering (which also uses Synchronize Model)

But when I connect to EER Diagram through reverse engineering again, One-to-one mapping changes to one-to-n-mapping.
(1: Parent / N : Child)

Here are the photos I captured.

1. user : teacher @OneToOne identification mapping

[image: one-to-one identification mapping]

2. forward Engeineering Success

[image]

3. Reconnect EER Diagram to reverse Engineering

[image]

I tried setting up **UQ** on user_id (fk,pk) in the teacher table and applied the **Synchronize Model**, but it doesn't work.

Let me know what bug it is.
Help me~

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer from the articles linked below.

The conclusion seems to have been the limitation of the forward and reverse engineering structure of MySql Workbench.

1: [after reverse Engineer MySQL Workbench change 1:1 relationship to 1:n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417257/after-reverse-engineer-mysql-workbench-change-11-relationship-to-1n)

2: [MySQL - One To One Relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644979/mysql-one-to-one-relation%EF%BB%BF)